# Ember property not being called

Tags: ember.js, properties, morris.js

I have been working on table that automatically makes a chart with the given information in the model. the problem I'm facing is that the property I've made in my component doesn't seem to get called. This is what I have at the moment:

```
App.ChartTestComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
data        : null,
isActive    : true,
dataArray   : [],
actions: {
    createGraph: function() {
        //console.log(this.data.content);
        //this.set('isActive', false);
        this.set('dataArray', this.getDataArray(this.get('data.content')));
        $('#car-chart').empty();

        Morris.Bar({
            element : 'car-chart',
            data    : this.get('dataArray'),
            xkey    : 'x',
            ykeys   : ['value'],
            labels  : ['Aantal']

        });
    }
},
getDataArray: function(model) {
    var returnArray = [];


    $.each(model, function(index, element) {
        returnArray.push({
            x       : element.get('brand'),
            value   : element.get('amountOfCars')
        });
    });

    //console.log(returnArray);
    return returnArray;
},
reloadData: function() {
    alert('Should work');
    this.set('dataArray', this.getDataArray(this.get('data.content')));
    return this.get('data');
}.observes('data')
//).observes('this.data')
```

What I'm trying to do is, whenever I change data in my table it has to automatically change the chart accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You say your property isn't being called, which makes me think there's an issue with a computed property, but you have no computed properties in the code you've given us. And if by property, you mean your `reloadData` function that observes your `data` property, it's not being called because you don't change the `data` property at all. Observers fire on changes.

Comment: hat I mean is, The data used in my Morris.Bar, get's changed everytime I change the input. So reloadData should be triggered, but this doesn't happen. My question is actually how can I fix it so reloadData will trigger after the data field in my Morris.Bar gets changed.

Comment: Are you changing the `data` property itself, or just it's contents? Because the observer will only fire if the actual `data` object changes. `this.set('data', {})` will fire the observer, `this.set('data.foo', {})` will not.

Comment: No, I'm actually changing the contents in `data`. I've tried using `.property` aswell but to no luck. I hope you can help me with this. The contents are: `x:` and `value:` in my `getDataArray`.

Comment: If you're only changing the contents, then you need to watch the contents. Use `.observes('data.x', 'data.value')` instead.